# Sqlbulkcopy error on WriteToServer; string cannot be converted to guid

Tags: c#, guid, sqlbulkcopy

Writing from Excel to SQL table using SQLBULKCOPY. The Excel has a GUID column and on some rows the value is empty.

When I WriteToServer, I get this error:

```
The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type 
uniqueidentifier of the specified target column.
```

The dest sql table is guid type on that field and it is nullable.

For now I'm not exporting that field and just setting it to default to newID() on the table itself.

But I would like to export the actual data from excel. Is there a setting on SQLBULKCOPY to handle this type of thing?

If not, any programmable ways to handle this situation?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".